# Magento Admin Account is Inactive

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

All my administrator accounts to login to the backend of the website is inactive. I cant login to change it because it shows access denied, how can i change it.

I have ftp access and cpanel access.

Answer (score 6):

In phpMyadmin go to admin_user table and you can edit is_active.
1 is active, 0 is not.

Afterwards, reset the Magento cache and you should be able to use the account to login.

If this value is already set to 1, then the account is active but you are not entering the correct password when you login.

If you have an email address associated with the account (and you can check that email), you can use the password reset functionality on the login page to have an update password link sent to your account so you can reset the password.

If you do NOT have an email address associated with the admin login, you will have to use [the instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983227/after-installing-magento-in-my-local-machine-i-forgot-admin-password) to manually update the password in phpMyAdmin and use the MD5 hashing algorithm to allow the account to log back in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i checked it was 1 already. The message it comes up is access denied

Comment: If it is set to 1 then the user is active.  The Access Denied message is telling you that you don't have the correct password for that user account.

Comment: Password is right if i place a wrong password it will say "Invalid User Name or Password."

Comment: You can try to clean up your browser's cash. or try to login from different browser, and delete cookies.

Comment: Can you confirm if the access denied message is being generated by Magento or your web server?  Perhaps share a screenshot?  If you're getting an apache or nginx access denied message, that's probably a file or directory permissions problem and not a Magento authentication error.

Comment: Ive cleared cache and changed browsers no luck,

Comment: https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=20979787532, here is the photo

Comment: I think its from magento, the time it stop working was when i tried to inactivate some admin user from the system which i didnt recognise, but not the one i was logged on. when i submitted my user became access denied

Answer (score 2):

Well if it's "Access denied" from Magento then, you can create another alternative admin account.

Login to phpmyadmin, select your Magento database and click on the "SQL" tab and run the following query.

```
LOCK TABLES `admin_role` WRITE , `admin_user` WRITE;

SET @SALT = "rp";
SET @PASS = CONCAT(MD5(CONCAT( @SALT , "password") ), CONCAT(":", @SALT ));
SELECT @EXTRA := MAX(extra) FROM admin_user WHERE extra IS NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO `admin_user` (firstname,lastname,email,username,password,created,lognum,reload_acl_flag,is_active,extra,rp_token_created_at) 
VALUES ('Firstname','Lastname','email@example.com','myuser',@PASS,NOW(),0,0,1,@EXTRA,NOW());

INSERT INTO `admin_role` (parent_id,tree_level,sort_order,role_type,user_id,role_name) 
VALUES (1,2,0,'U',(SELECT user_id FROM admin_user WHERE username = 'myuser'),'Firstname');

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Set 'Username' and 'Password' to your choice.

Then you can login with the newly created Admin account and verify or change access restrictions by navigating to:

```
System > Permissions > Users
```

and

```
System > Permissions > Roles
```

Visit this [tutorial](http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/users-and-user-roles) for more info on "Roles and User management".

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Shall i just copy and paste the above code into the sql query and where shall i place the username and pass

Comment: Yes just paste the above code into "SQL" tab. Replace 'myuser'(keep the single quotes), in both the `INSERT INTO...` queries, with your desired username and "password"(keep the double quotes) in line `SET @PASS = CONCAT(MD5(CONCAT( @SALT , "password") ), CONCAT(":", @SALT ));` with your desired password. Then execute the query.

Answer (score 2):

I have to add that this also sounds like an issue that I've encountered recently with the user's role. If you by accident set your user's group's resource access to `custom` without checking any values (I did), you will be completely locked out of the admin panel.

You need to make sure that the values in the `admin_role` and `admin_rule` tables are correct to give your user complete access.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear your cookies... Admin can block access.

Check var folders owner and rights if you use file sessions.